# Need help parsing a table with rvest into dataframe

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=USDOT&original_query_param=NAME&query_string=2249709&original_query_string=ARKANSAS%20BEST%20LOGISTICS%20INC

I need to parse the table under inspections/crashes in the US from the webpage above into an R dataframe. The parsing technique that worked for some of the tables on the site is not working for others.

I was able to parse the inspections table with the following code:

```
    inspections <- carrier %>%
      html_node('.querylabel+ center table') %>%
      html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

But when I try to parse the crashes table which is right underneath the inspections table I get the error:

```
    Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
      no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class 
    "xml_missing"
```

I used the following code:

```
    crashes <- carrier %>%
      html_node('center:nth-child(19) table') %>%
      html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

I used selector gadget to select the css which for that table was 'center:nth-child(19) table'. I also tried using html_node() with an x path:

```
    crashes <- carrier %>%
      html_node(xpath = '//center[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 
     19) and parent::*)]//table') %>%
      html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

That didn't work either. I am very new to webscraping so I apologize if this is a simple solution.

carrier is the url:

```
    carrier <- read_html(https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=USDOT&original_query_param=NAME&query_string=2249709&original_query_string=ARKANSAS%20BEST%20LOGISTICS%20INC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two "Inspections" tables, and two "Crashes" tables, one each for US and Canada. Here's two ways of approaching it:

1. Use the preceding links ("Inspections:", "Crashes:") to identify the `center` element following the link. Then look for the `table` node, and parse it.

---

```
library(rvest)
dot_url <- 
  "https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=USDOT&original_query_param=NAME&query_string=2249709&original_query_string=ARKANSAS%20BEST%20LOGISTICS%20INC" %>% 
  read_html()

dot_url %>% 
  html_node("a[href$='#Inspections'] + center") %>% 
  html_node("table") %>% 
  html_table()
```

> ```
>               Inspection Type Vehicle Driver Hazmat IEP
> 1                 Inspections       0      0      0   0
> 2              Out of Service       0      0      0   0
> 3            Out of Service %      0%     0%     0%  0%
> 4 Nat'l Average %(2009- 2010)  20.72%  5.51%  4.50% N/A
> ```

```
dot_url %>% 
  html_node("a[href$='#Accidents'] + center") %>% 
  html_node("table") %>% 
  html_table()
```

> ```
>      Type Fatal Injury Tow Total
> 1 Crashes     0      0   0     0
> ```

You can also do this for Canada with `a[href$='#InspectionsCA'] ...` but the formatting isn't ideal (the "Crashes:" table has the same `href` value). (Note that `href$=` means the link ends in that text: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#selectors.)

---

2. Get both sets of the "Inspections" and "Crashes" tables, using the `summary` field of the tables and name them (using e.g. `purrr::set_names` and `c("US", "Canada")`), or discard the ones you don't want (using `[[`):

---

```
dot_url %>% 
  html_nodes("table[summary='Inspections']") %>% 
  html_table()
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>               Inspection Type Vehicle Driver Hazmat IEP
> 1                 Inspections       0      0      0   0
> 2              Out of Service       0      0      0   0
> 3            Out of Service %      0%     0%     0%  0%
> 4 Nat'l Average %(2009- 2010)  20.72%  5.51%  4.50% N/A
>
> [[2]]
>    Inspection Type Vehicle Driver
> 1      Inspections       0      0
> 2   Out of Service       0      0
> 3 Out of Service %      0%     0%
> ```

```
dot_url %>% 
  html_nodes("table[summary='Crashes']") %>% 
  html_table()
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>      Type Fatal Injury Tow Total
> 1 Crashes     0      0   0     0
>
> [[2]]
>      Type Fatal Injury Tow Total
> 1 Crashes     0      0   0     0
> ```

Comment: Very nice answer +

Comment: @gizaom if the answer worked perfectly then you should accept it by clicking the ✓. That way others will also know what worked for you.